# Execute Transaction Mysql in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to run this query in my Java program :

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO Term(mot) VALUES ('NAN');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @term_id;
INSERT INTO Paragraphe(xpath,idDoc) VALUES ('/BALADE/doc','d001.xml');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @parag_id;
INSERT INTO occurrence(occurrence) VALUES (22);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @occur_id;
INSERT INTO Term_Parag(id_term,id_parag,id_occur) VALUES (@term_id, @parag_id,@occur_id);
COMMIT;
```

When I run the program like this I get an error :

```
query = "START TRANSACTION; "+
                         "INSERT INTO Term(mot) VALUES (?); "+
                         "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @term_id; "+
                         "INSERT INTO Paragraphe(xpath,idDoc) VALUES (?,?); "+
                         "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @parag_id; "+
                         "INSERT INTO occurrence(occurrence) VALUES (?); "+
                         "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @occur_id; "+
                         "INSERT INTO Term_Parag(id_term,id_parag,id_occur) VALUES (@term_id, @parag_id,@occur_id); "+
                         "COMMIT;";

                ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                ps.setString(1, unWord.content);
                ps.setString(2, unWord.path);
                ps.setString(3, doc);
                ps.setInt(4, unWord.occurence);

                ps.execute();
```

When I run the query directly in Mysql PHPmyadmin it works. Help !

Comment: Have you set the allowMultiQueries to true?   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: This is not a query. It's 9 queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by making a stored procedure in Mysql and call it from my Java program.